# Having some trouble with jQuery scrollTop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scrolltop

ive been researching a ton on this and am coming up at a loss.

Not really sure what is going on, but I can't get this .animate() to animate properly.

I made a JS fiddle outlining the way I have things set up. Basically, its 4 slides, each is 100% height and 100% width, I am getting the slide target dynamically from each link in each slide.

I made a jsFiddle to try and get it to work properly:

http://jsfiddle.net/mikelegacy/WrZev/

Here is the jquery I am using, you'll have to look at the jsFiddle to get the full scope of things, though.

```
$("a.scrollButton").click(function(e) {
    var slideId = $(this).attr("href");
        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: $(slideId).offset().top
        }, 2000);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change a.scrollButton to a.slideButton as you have it in your HTML.

```
$("a.slideButton").click(function(e) {
    var slideId = $(this).attr("href");
        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: $(slideId).offset().top
        }, 2000); 
    return false;

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/WrZev/2/

Comment: I'd suggest adding `return false` to this handler: without it there's a visible glitch in Firefox, at least.

Comment: Fair enough, I test in Chrome so didn't notice anything, thanks for that.

Comment: Crap, that's a stupid mistake on the JSFiddle, not sure why, but I double checked in my actual code, and I do have the correct selector set and it's still not working. Obviously something else on the page is messing up the function...

Comment: yep, must be something else interfering. Use Chrome, right click the page, choose inspect element and change to the console tab, that will show you any js errors that are occurring, could be something as simple as a small typo, and likely is.

Comment: It might be something more silent, the only javascript error I have is chrome telling me it's unsafe to access youtube.com in an iFrame from my url.

Comment: Try running it through validator.w3.org maybe it's a simple HTML error throwing the scroll?